# why NaN that returned from a function is not falsy value?

Tags: javascript

how we can falsy value from a returned function.

I have a function block that from the returned value  we make decisions and with an undefined value or NaN value we should have a false value how can I reach that?

for example

```
console.log(Boolean(() =\>{return NaN})
```

is true

Comment: In javascript, functions are first class citizens. You are converting the function itself, and never calling it. Any object is truthy. PS: I ignored the rogue backslash in your code, which appears to be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function objects are always `true` when converted to boolean. You want to convert the *return value* of the function to a boolean, so you need to call the function.

```js
console.log(Boolean((() => {return NaN})()));
// or more explicitly:
const f = () => NaN;
console.log(Boolean(f())); // equivalent to !!f()
```